# Ruby on Rails form helper issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a tricky scenario I need to implement and can't figure out how to do it.  I'm trying to create a form that passes its data in a hash labelled 'message' to a controller that will then create a message object, but I can't use form_for because I need to use hidden_field tag and not hidden_field.

Here is the form I have so far:

```
=form_tag(:action => 'create', :controller => 'messages', :method => :get) do
        =text_area :message, :message, :size => '40x5'
        =hidden_field_tag(:message, :subject => "RE:#{@message.subject}")
        =hidden_field_tag(:message, :parent => @message.id)
        =hidden_field_tag(:message, :receiver => @message.sender)
        =submit_tag 'Reply'
```

I want the controller to receive:

```
{"message"=>"{:message=>"How are you?", :subject=>"Hi", :parent=>nil, :receiver=>2}", "commit"=>"Reply", "method"=>"get", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"messages"}
```

however,  I'm receiving:

```
{"message"=>"{:receiver=>2}", "commit"=>"Reply", "method"=>"get", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"messages"}
```

and the value of the text area is being given the value of the message I'm replying to.
Can anyone help me?

Edit:  Upon implementing Russell's answer, I now receive:

```
Message(#39922460) expected, got String(#15633780)
```

Here's the full trace:

```
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:204:in `raise_on_type_mismatch'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/associations/belongs_to_association.rb:6:in `replace'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/associations/singular_association.rb:17:in `writer'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:51:in `block in define_writers'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:85:in `block in assign_attributes'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:78:in `each'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:78:in `assign_attributes'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/base.rb:498:in `initialize'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/validations.rb:39:in `new'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/validations.rb:39:in `create!'
app/controllers/messages_controller.rb:13:in `create'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:425:in `_run__3805623263237724248__process_action__1465637019578896381__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:612:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__3699448979629391707__call__1119864259513439622__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/home/renee/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/home/renee/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/home/renee/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you probably want something closer to this (not tested):

```
=form_tag(:action => 'create', :controller => 'messages', :method => :get) do
    =text_area "message[message]", :size => '40x5'
    =hidden_field_tag("message[subject]", "RE:#{@message.subject}")
    =hidden_field_tag("message[parent]", @message.id)
    =hidden_field_tag("message[receiver]", @message.sender)
    =submit_tag 'Reply'
```

Comment: So I gave this a try and now I'm getting a 'message expected, got string instead' when I try to create the message

Comment: Can you post the backtrace? Are the params being sent to the controller as you'd expect?

Comment: They are.  I raised and inspected and they are exactly as they should be.  Even more, I call the create action with another form that sends the same params and it works.